# Python: how to constantly update text lines

Tags: python, text, readline

i have a list of 20 lines, either a 0 or a 2. right now i have it rewriting the 20 lines of the text files based off ping results. i'm having a seperate program read that 20 lines, but it generates errors when there is not 20 lines (as the text file is being written). How can i edit each individual text line without rewriting the document?

```
    ping ip
    if ping == 0
       f= open("status", 'ab')
       f.write("0\n")
       f.close
```

thats one condition on how it writes. i do wipe the document before this executes.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're trying to pass real time data here... Programs should not communicate in real time through files. That's not stable as well as **awfully slow**. if that's not the case you may want to rewrite the file opening it with `w` (write) instead of `a` (append).

Comment: Agreed. What you should instead be doing, is working with pipes.

Comment: The file might be a named pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the use of *constantly* in the title correctly, you're trying to pass real time data here... Programs should not communicate in real time through files. That's not stable as well as **awfully slow**. if that's not the case you may want to rewrite the file opening it with `w` (write) instead of `a` (append).

```
if ping == 0
   with open("status", 'wb') as f:
       # write all 20 lines
```

Read more about [modes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

**note:** to actually close a file you should **call** `file.close` by using `f.close()` and not `f.close`. If you're using `with` as a context manager like I suggest, the file is closed once the context is over (indentation returns to `with` level).

Comment: I have an LED strip that is displaying a color based on that 0 or 2. I did have it reading off the document. But you guys are right, it is unstable and slow. I've modified it somewhat, and i think ive figured out how to just update the status without using a text file. I'll close this question when i can. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Maybe you should just accept so that others with looking for similar problems can find an answer. I'll also get 15 points for helping :)